# Wouldn't work to overlay two images in Mail HTML

Tags: html, css, email

I'm trying to put two images on top of each other in the HTML of an email, but it fails. It displays fine in normal HTML, but when it comes to the email layout, it collapses.

**code**

```
<td className="icon">
   <img class="block" src='./img/b.png' />
   <img src='./img/a.png' />
</td>

<style>
.block {
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
</style>
```

`margin` isn't working totally.

Do you have any ideas in MAIL HTML?

*ideal:*
[image]

*issue:*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think your "td" with the icon class should have a bigger width in your layout. So the margin of -40px does not work right. I guess you can try hardcode the icon width, increase the negative margin value or position your images as absolute within your container.

I also leave this "logo" draw with CSS below. I hope it can help you a little. (You can change the width and height of the container for your needs).

HTML

```
<div class="circles-container">
<div class="circle circle1"></div>
<div class="circle circle2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circles-container{
position: relative;
display: flex;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: transparent;
}

.circle{      
position: absolute;
top:0;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.circle1{
left: 33%;
background-color: #3484b9;
}

.circle2{
left: 66%;
background-color: #ffd61e;
}
```